# Apache URL Rewriting for multiple dynamic folder levels

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Wondering if somebody can help me write some RewriteRule's for my website.

Take a look at the following URLs and see how I need to rewrite them.

```
http://www.example.com/essays-and-reports/ 
does not need to be re-written, it is a physical folder on the web server.

http://www.example.com/essays-and-reports/business/ 
needs to rewrite to (root)/first_level_template.php

http://www.example.com/essays-and-reports/dynamic_name2
needs to rewrite to (root)/first_level_template.php

http://www.example.com/essays-and-reports/business/financial-reports/ 
needs to rewrite to (root)/second_level_template.php

http://www.example.com/essays-and-reports/blah/financial-reports/C_B_2413_Report_on_savings.php 
needs to rewrite to (root)/final_level_template.php
```

Note the rules must work regardless of a trailing slash.  To sum-up, there are three levels which I need to re-write to their relevant template. None of above exists physically on the server including the PHP file for final level. The only thing that exists is the essays-and-reports folder which is main folder for the website.

I tried something like this but I get compile errors in the log.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /second-level-template\.php [L]
```

If you could help me write the rules I need - I appreciate it greatly.

**EDIT:**
This code kind of works but it also rewrites the essays-and-reports folder which I don't want...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /essays-and-dissertations/
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ /final_level_template.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ /second_level_template.php [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ /first_level_template.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 3 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^essays-and-reports/[^/]+/?$ /first_level_template.php [L]
RewriteRule ^essays-and-reports/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ /second_level_template.php [L]
RewriteRule ^essays-and-reports/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/?$ /final_level_template.php [L]
```

You don't need to escape the dot in your redirect target, since that's not a regular expression.

Comment: Blast - doesn't seem to work - perhaps my Apache is not configured properly? I just get a 404 errors.

Comment: see code above in my edit, managed to get something working but its not perfect.

Comment: NOTE: essays-and-dissertations is just another part of my website.